# I cannot find Widgets under Apperance>Windgets in WordPress 4.2.9

Tags: wordpress, widget

Fresh WordPress Install. Used it for a couple of days with no issue until I tried adding a text widget. The Widgets menu is not under Apperance>Windgets. Not sure what's going on here. Please help.

Was it moved moved in the new version?

Wordpress v4.2.9

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVcPD.png

Comment: check the functions.php file in source code

Comment: Hello Priyanka Modi? What should I look for or change in the functions.php file? Thanks.

Comment: again replace with new file of functions.php with new version and check it

Comment: @SolomonMokua Try switching the Theme.

Comment: Thanks Guys, it now working. Theme support updated the theme.@Priyanka Modi, tried your method and it worked too.